Solr highlight several search words in long text
I have a multiValued stored text field in solr with a lot of text per document. I have a search query "Word1 Word2". The document is pretty long and contains/might contain the "Word1" many times. The "Word2" is almost/might be at the bottom.
The highlighter only highlights the first word "Word1". If I enable more snippets or longer snippets, the Word1 dominates, the Word2 is never highlighted.
Is there any way to create a highlight snippets that will contain both of the query words repeating only once ?
Example:
Snippet1: Lorem ipsum WORD1 Lorem ipsum
Snippet2: Lorem ipsum WORD2 Lorem ipsum".
Also there can be more words spread all over the document. Is it possible to show a snippets for all the words only once (if they are not next to each other) ?
